# how to close combobox when onmouseout?

Tags: javascript, html

How to close combobox when onmouseout?

```
<select onmouseout="">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this (reliably). The popup that appears is not available to manipulate, ie open or close, programmatically and its behaviour is defined by the browser (or operating system).

To expand on this further, both IE and Firefox can close the popup by blurring the select element:

```
selectEl.blur();
```

Although, the *mouseout* event fires even when you move the mouse to the options in the popup, so it would require a bit of hackery magic.  In Chrome it will blur the select element but the box will remain open.

It's generally best to leave the behaviour of UI components alone, so that users get the experience they expect through interaction with your website.

Comment: hmm, can we do click to mouse's position or anywhere when it onmouseout.
I think if we can do this, combobox closes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick like this...

```
<select onmouseover="size = 5" onmouseout="size = 0">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This will expand the menu on mouse over then collapse it when you move out.

Edit: This can cause issues with placement of other elements if you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years late but in case someone else is looking at this...I was able to toggle the open/close state of a select element in Chrome by sending it a mouse click.  In this example moving the mouse over the toggle button will toggle the state of the `<select>`.  This is a toggle, not an explicit open or close, but worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function clickSelect(element) {
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    };

    function toggleSelect() {
        clickSelect(document.getElementById("select"));
    }  
</script>


<form>
    <select id="select">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onmouseover="toggleSelect();" value="toggle select state" />
</form>
```