# I want to change combobox when mouse is on it or when its not

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my application i need ... if a user click on combobox it will work as usual like show all the list and when mouse is not on any of item or on combobox...then that combobox should take its default position .... that mean it must compress again

in jquery or javascript..you can post your answer ...
 i just want solution :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to close combobox when onmouseout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132963/how-to-close-combobox-when-onmouseout)

Comment: @andy but am not getting this one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `<select>` tag:

```
<select onmouseout="JavaScript: this.blur();">
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: its working in firefox ...which i need basically...

can u tell me how make i make it work on IE too