# How do I close a combo box with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to javascript, so please forgive my ignorance.  I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be incredibly simple...close a combo box.  However, when I use the hide() function, it not only closes the combo box, but it removes it entirely.  Is there any way to just close it?

EDIT:

Here's the actual code I'm using

```
$(window).ready(function ()
{
    $('#comboBox .dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function ()
    {
        $("#comboBox").hide();
    });
});
```

This removes the combo box from the page when the mouse leaves the open combo box.  If I replace hide with blur, nothing happens at all.

Edit 2:

Here's the code for my actual list:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="comboBox">
                    <button class="btn btn-custom-top dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caption"></span><span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    </ul>
</div>
```

Edit 3:

Alright, I was obviously confused about what I was doing.  No surprise there, as I'm very new to all this.  It's not actually a combo box that I'm trying to close.  It's a bootstrap dropdown button type, which doesn't really have the same behavior as a combo box.  It's looking like there is no function ready-made to do what I want.

Comment: what do you mean by `close a combo box`. Can you post your code what you tried so far?

Comment: this question seems to suggest that it's different on different browsers. but the question is pretty old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132963/how-to-close-combobox-when-onmouseout

Comment: `.hide()` is a jQuery function. If you're using jQuery, please tag your question with it, in addition to showing your code.

Comment: hide() sounds like jquery so I go and guess that you should use `.prop("disabled",true)` http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I assume that what the OP is trying to do is not actually to hide nor to disable the combo box, but to hide the select popup that is shown when you click on it.  You might try sending it a "blur" event.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm using jQuery.  And by "close combo box" I mean that I want it to do the opposite of what happens when you first click on it, but I don't want it to disappear from the page and I don't want to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a DOM `select` element, then the best you can do is call `blur()`, which will close it.

Comment: I've tried blur in both IE and Firefox and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @mrplainswalker Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HFUq4/2/ I tested it with firefox and chrome.

Comment: Your code works for me...so maybe it's my container type?  I posted my html as well.

Comment: @mrplainswalker So, you don't have a select element, which means blur() can't work. Take a look at this article that shows how to set up the css for a jquery drop-down http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/

Answer (score 0):

You should call its [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event handler, here is the code using jQuery:

```
$('#yourSelectId').blur();
```